UI Extension DevServer returns 404 not found
I am trying to use the development server shipped with UI Exensions react app, when running the server and open https://localhost:3000/ui in the browser I got HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
I added https://localhost:3000/ui/signin-oidc to allowed redirects url for Tridion Sites Experience Space in Access Management, I've also added http://domainname:3000/ui/signin-oidc ( domainname of the CMS ) based on the accepted answer here GUI extensions for Experience Space - Not working on Local
Are there more required config to make this work?

Is that your cms setup endpoint uses https?

It is, but when I added http://localhost:3000/ui/signin-oidc it worked! Thanks for the hint @Velmurugan

We've recently updated documentation for extension examples. It now includes steps for https environments. Can you check it and see if it helps?
https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/tree/main/sites-10-ux-update
In general, if you see 404, it means you are reaching wrong environment.
